# How can I filter on Windows-based or Linux-based containers within Docker Hub?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, containers, dockerhub

I recently started exploring the wonderful world of containers. Obviously boot2docker enables us for quite some time now to run Linux-based containers on a Windows platform. Recently Microsoft has released native Windows-based container support as part of their new OS platforms Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10 Pro and up, which enables us to run native Windows containers! See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/

First thing that I noticed is that the available container images on Docker Hub are not interchangable. One needs to pick a Linux-based container image for the Linux-based Docker/container host and a Windows-based container image for the Windows-based container host. I.e.:

- When one tries to install a Windows-based container on a Linux-based container host you will get the error message `unknown blob`. Just try to install the image https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnet/ yourself.
- When one tries to install a Linux-based container on a Windows-based container host you will get the error message `image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform`. E.g. just pick https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/

That leads to my question: I find it quite difficult, within Docker Hub, to find the suitable container image for the right platform. Is there a way to filter on the required container base?

Answer (score 6):

OK, I just found out that there is a new platform called Docker Store, https://store.docker.com/

They provide the filter I was looking for:

[image: Docker Store OS filter]

Regrettably one can only filter the official store templates/registry. When browsing through the community templates, the filter option is greyed out.